# Paypal subscription "custom" variable issue ( Sandbox )

Tags: php, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I've created a paypal button from their button template creator, I **need** to send them a custom variable which contains the users ID.

*So I can then use it to further identify the user and update their specific records*

However the template for the button as given by paypal **was**:

```
                    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CVWJZN5AALBVJ">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>
```

**And I altered it to:**

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="CVWJZN5AALBVJ">
                    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
                    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>
```

Essentially just adding this line

```
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

But when my IPN is called, I did a var dump and the custom variable is **NOT** being sent with the other post variables

*This is the data I'm receiving when I go through the subscription payment **( From the var dump)***

```
Array
(
    [txn_type] => subscr_signup
    [subscr_id] => I-TUUWHD0V6T4Y
    [last_name] => buyer
    [residence_country] => GB
    [mc_currency] => GBP
    [item_name] => premium membership
    [business] => dddd-facilitator@hotmail.com
    [recurring] => 1
    [address_street] => 1 Main Terrace
    [verify_sign] => AStwKS3.L4rNUPfkl7TOO9eahVmAABKWlAKqXwDrHAOGmGfwPvaWdtSg
    [payer_status] => verified
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [payer_email] =>dddd-buyer@hotmail.com
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [first_name] => test
    [receiver_email] => dddd-facilitator@hotmail.com
    [address_country_code] => GB
    [payer_id] => 7RUAE8WJDD4V2
    [address_city] => Wolverhampton
    [reattempt] => 1
    [address_state] => West Midlands
    [subscr_date] => 12:42:12 Oct 26, 2015 PDT
    [btn_id] => 3228524
    [address_zip] => W12 4LQ
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [period3] => 1 M
    [address_country] => United Kingdom
    [mc_amount3] => 10.00
    [address_name] => test buyer
    [ipn_track_id] => 21e04b9a73c5
)
```

I want to see `[custom] => "usersid"`
Any pointers?

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue because the button is hosted by them. Have you tried using a custom button instead of a hosted button? Here is an example of a custom checkout button: http://pastebin.com/VCaK4dtu (Note: that code is a modified version of the checkout button code I am using on one of my e-commerce websites.)

Comment: @SpencerDoak thanks for the reply, I found the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The problem was that the ID column in the database was in capitals:*

**I had**

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

**when it should have been**

```
$id = $row['ID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a generated by paypal button ( with id CVWJZN5AALBVJ )! **This button submit what you add as parameters inside the paypal administration, not what parameter you add inside button form**. You must use a custom form to submit following this example:

```
<form method="post" name="checkout-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@paypal_email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="22" >
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="65">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="YOUR PRODUCT ID OR SOME CUSTOM CODE">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://zoomthe.me/paypalipn/paypal_ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://zoomthe.me/paypal_cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Product Description">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://zoomthe.me/your_listener_ipn_file.php">
</form>
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but thanks for the comment